# Jquery Timer To server time

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a game where i need the user to enter a deadline time using a jquery dateTime plugin (my PC time) and i save it in the database along with the current time using php (server time).. Then i run a cron (on the server time) where i need the difference of these two times for further work. but there is a logical error here.

I checked and the difference between the times was of 10 hours and 3 mins. so i adjusted that but this will give a logical error if it is used from some other place,, as teh jquery will pick up their PC time and php will pick the sever time.

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get more logical results you should be aware of different timezones.

On the JavaScript site you can use `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` or `Date.toUTCString();`

See the following links for example:

[JavaScript getTimezoneOffset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) 
[JavaScript toUTCString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp)